# Backstage Unable to use mkdocs to create Tech Docs for an existing component

Tags: mkdocs, backstage

I have enabled Github actions to create Tech docs after a commit. Below is the workflow file written to create Md files. But "techdocs-cli generate --no-docker --verbose" command fails with the below error. Can someone please help with the issue?

**Failed to generate docs from /home/runner/work/myapp3/myapp3 into /home/runner/work/myapp3/myapp3/site; caused by unknown error 'Command mkdocs failed, exit code: 1'**

workflow file:

```
name: Publish TechDocs Site
on:
 push:
 branches: master

jobs:
 publish-techdocs-site:
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  env:
  TECHDOCS_S3_BUCKET_NAME: XXX
  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: XXX
  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: XXX
  AWS_REGION:  XXX
  ENTITY_NAMESPACE: 'default'
  ENTITY_KIND: 'Component'
  ENTITY_NAME: ‘XXX’

steps:
  - name: Checkout code
    uses: actions/checkout@v2

  - uses: actions/setup-node@v2
  - uses: actions/setup-python@v2

  - name: Install techdocs-cli
    run: sudo npm install -g @techdocs/cli

  - name: Install mkdocs and mkdocs plugins
    run: python -m pip install mkdocs-techdocs-core==1.*

  - name: Generate docs site
    run: techdocs-cli generate --no-docker --verbose

  - name: Publish docs site
    run: techdocs-cli publish --publisher-type awsS3 --storage-name $TECHDOCS_S3_BUCKET_NAME --entity $ENTITY_NAMESPACE/$ENTITY_KIND/$ENTITY_NAME
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and it was resolved once you had the right folder structure where you have the `mkdocs.yml` file.

As long as you have a `docs` folder in the same root structure with the `.md file` that needs to be published.

The same `.md file` needs to be configured in the navigation section of the `mkdocs.yml` file as well